# How can I connect a portable dishwasher to laundry hookups?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, dishwasher

I just moved into new duplex that has a decent sized laundry room. During my move I brought my portable compact dishwasher ([very similar to this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052FXC9Y)). I don't have counter-top space to position the dishwasher near the sink since it requires the sink faucet hookup by default. I have some extra space in the laundry room and I'm considering splitting the water and drain hookups for the washing machine to accommodate the washing machine and dishwasher.

Is this something that would be possible without too much trouble? If so what would be the best way to go about making this type of modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much trouble will depend on if you need to keep the quick disconnect device or not. If it needs to remain, you will need to somehow transition from a hose end fitting of the washer connection to whatever threading your disconnect adapter that fits on the faucet uses. I know I've seen faucet to hose adapters, but there will be a gender issue where both adapters are male, requiring a femalexfemale faucet coupler, which I've never seen.

Another issue is how to connect the existing drain outlet to an extension hose running to the washer drain. This may be easy or difficult, depending on the drain outlet configuration. These quick disconnects seem to be prone to slight leakage, not a problem over the sink. Consider the implications of a possible leak in the laundry room.

If you are willing to cut off the quick disconnect (I assume it is like others I've seen that are swagged connections with no way to disassemble it) then it's a pretty straight forward matter of acquiring standard brass garden hose fittings and fitting them to the cut hose ends. Before proceeding with irrevocable cutting, try to ascertain that the inside hose diameters are compatible with available fittings.

As long as the hoses are of compatible size and short lengths of hose remain attached to the quick disconnect, you can reattach the disconnect using brass hose couplers, though of course the couplers will become a permanent part of the assembly from here on out.

All hose fittings must be secured with screw drive clamps for leak proof connections, thus the specification of brass fittings. Plastic fittings will not hold up to the pressures from a firm clamp installation.

Comment: I was easily able to dissemble the quick disconnect last night. I took it down to my local hardware store to try and find hoses and adapters that might work. The water inlet isn't too much trouble, its a standard 1/2 in hose hookup -- I have an extra washing machine hose I can use. I found the drain hookup to be the issue. It's a smaller hose (3/8 or something I think), so getting it to fit to the drain hookup is seeming to be more challenging. I have a set of PVC adapters and bushings that I'm going to try and use.

Comment: Sounds promising. The water supply was critical because it must hold pressure. If need be, you can get by with less than ideal connectors for the drain because it is not high pressure. While you really want to find barbed connectors, you could get by with a short length of copper tubing and some hose clamps provided the tubing is a good snug fit. Also check auto parts stores for hose connector possibilities. Happy hunting.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. I have a barbed connector off the back of the dishwasher that runs to a T-Adapter on the drain through a standard dishwasher discharge hose. The other end has another barb and 3/4 to 1in adapter that connect it to the 1in T. I have the washing machine drain through the top, and the dishwasher through the front. So far so good. It's working pretty slick. [drain hookup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjh6y44a9mvvpqj/IMAG0069.jpg)
[washer back](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5mc6mw8m03htgm/IMAG0068.jpg)

Comment: Looks pretty tidy considering what's all involved. Good work! I'm glad it worked out for you. I'd be really surprised if this setup gives you any trouble.

Comment: Thanks! It's working pretty well. I've use the full setup about 4 or 5 times now. No problems.

Comment: @keannan5390 The dropbox image seems to have disappeared. Care to upload it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Thank you both for your comments and suggestions! I think I took a similar route to what you did. Here are the parts that made it all happen. This is for the water input. [image]
And this is for the drain hose. [image]

For the water input hose, I used a clothes washer size hose (3/4 inch) and converted it down two steps. First to 1/2 inch. Then to 3/8 inch. Then I put a brass barb converter on the end of the water hose from the dishwasher.  [image]

I used a Y splitter at the pipe hookup. 
 [image]

For the drain pipe, I used a regular dishwasher to sink drain pipe, but then left the top open so my washer can drain down the top and the dishwasher drains into the side. 
[image]

So far I have ran two cycles with no issues. We'll see how it holds up in the long run!

I took more detailed photos each step of the way, so if anyone is interested in them just let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate these photos and this detail. wondering what is that white drain pipe called that has the side connection ? or did you make that yourself? thank you.

Comment: That white drain pipe with the side connection is a dishwasher branch tailpiece.