# Hook up portable washing machine to the regular water pipes already on the wall

Tags: plumbing

What do I need to hook up a portable washer to the regular hook up for a normal size washing machine. I cannot get a new washing machine in the laundry room area so I have to go with a portable. The hot and cold pipes are there but portables only have one inlet hose.

Comment: Is there still an old washing machine in the laundry room?

Comment: Do the directions for the portable suggest that you would be connecting to a typical kitchen faucet? With the kitchen arrangements you can pre-select the water temperature depending upon how you set the hot/cold mix.

Comment: This has been asked and answered.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27581/how-can-i-connect-a-portable-dishwasher-to-laundry-hookups  It seams like a lot of work to convert it when you could POSSIBLY find a machine that will fit through your door, but i do not know why you can not fit a new machine?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.